# How to change jar output directory when running as maven install in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, minecraft, bukkit, maven-install-plugin

I am making a Minecraft plugin for Bukkit 1.8, and everything works fine. I right click on the project name > Run As > Maven install. It outputs the .jar file to the `target` directory. I then copy the file to the `plugins` folder of my Minecraft server.

I would like to have it output the jar directly into my `plugins` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do that would be to bind an execution of the [`maven-antrun-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/index.html) to the `install` phase. This execution would copy the main artifact to the Minecraft server folder.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>install</phase>
      <configuration>
        <target>
          <copy file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"
                todir="/path/to/server/plugins" />
        </target>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

(This snippet must be placed inside the `<build><plugins>` element).

Running `mvn clean install` (or "Run As... > Maven Install" in Eclipse), Maven will do what you want. `${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar` refers to the main artifact present in the build directory (which is `target` by default). You'll need to update the path to the server in the snippet above.